# Can't paint weight for specific bone

Tags: bones, weight-painting

I'm new to this whole thing, and I'm running into a problem where I'm trying to paint weights, and it's going fine, except for one bone that only lets me paint the opposite half of the model I'm working on. Everything else works fine except for that one bone.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe there's a flipped normal?

Comment: Sounds like a mirroring issue-- check the name of the bone and its symmetrical opposite, make sure they use the same .L/.R designation as the rest of the bones.  If that's not the problem, consider linking a file for better answers.

Comment: Wow I feel dumb, I guess I'd gotten the .L/.Rs mixed up somewhere along the way. Thank you Nathan.